# My NULL record isn't showing up despite adding a WHERE IS NULL clause

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a database that looks a bit like this:

Table 1: ------------------- Table 2:

```
ID1|Item Name        ID2|Date
---|----------       ---|---------
1  |A                1  |01/01/2020
2  |B                1  |11/01/2020
3  |C                1  |21/01/2020
                     2  |01/01/2020
```

What I want is to get the latest date of each item, even if it has none:

```
Item Name|Latest Date
---------|-----------
A        |21/01/2020
B        |01/01/2020
C        |NULL
```

So I did this:

```
SELECT [Item Name], [Date] AS [Latest Date]
FROM [Table 1]
LEFT JOIN [Table 2] AS A
ON [ID1] = [ID2]
WHERE [Date] IN
(
    SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [Table 2] AS B
    WHERE A.[ID2] = B.[ID2]
)
OR [Date] IS NULL
```

But what I get instead is this:

```
Item Name|Latest Date
---------|-----------
A        |21/01/2020
B        |01/01/2020
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get C to show up?

I am aware that the WHERE clause gets rid of it, but since I added an IS NULL check, shouldn't it appear too?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://rextester.com/ZWVS37019). I get exactly what you expect.

Comment: You should be seeing C's record with that SQL and data. Make sure that your SQL is exactly like you posted.

Comment: also unable to [reproduce](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVGrjxMS8YdziCgeUej8r/0).  Realise mine is MySQL but the principle is the same (and SQLite fiddle gives same result as well)

Comment: You've already asked this same effective question and marked an answer - this is just a wrinkle on the "first per group" concept. You have aggregation suggestions for doing this without row_number - but I think it likely that you over-simplified the query and those will be insufficient to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @SMor The other question is now over, this is a totally different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found out why, and I must be dumb.

I have another JOIN clause, but I tested my query without it and I got the unwanted result. so I left it out of the question. After I saw multiple users couldn't reproduce, I tried again without the other join, and I got a satisfactory result. My guess is that I forgot the WHERE [Date] IS NULL clause when I tested that.

Basically, I now have exactly what I want

Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT A.[Item Name], MAX(B.[Date]) AS [Latest Date]
FROM [Table 1] AS A LEFT JOIN [Table 2] AS B ON A.[ID1] = B.[ID2]
GROUP BY A.[Item Name]
ORDER BY A.[Item Name] ASC
```

You don't have to check the date in the `WHERE` clause. You can `LEFT JOIN` the two tables and `GROUP BY` item names. With `MAX` you get the last date of each group.

Comment: This is not giving as OP expected please check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b0d12293395296780d3ce9c13e09cd5

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to get the max date for each ID, and then join that to the items:

```sql
SELECT T1.[Item Name], T2.[Date] AS [Latest Date]
FROM [Table 1] AS T1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ID2, MAX(Date) AS [Date]
        FROM [Table 2] AS T2
        GROUP BY ID2
    ) AS T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an analytical function to get latest value, like this:

```
WITH Resultset
AS
(SELECT
        [Item Name]
       ,[DATE]
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID1 ORDER BY [Date] DESC) rn
    FROM [Table 1]
    LEFT JOIN [Table 2] AS A
        ON [ID1] = [ID2])
SELECT
    [Item Name]
   ,[DATE]
FROM Resultset
WHERE rn = 1
```

Here you order by the [Date] columns, and always get the lates row, if it exists from Table 2.

If there are more columns in table2, it is easy to get the lates value, by date

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative in which you can declare a variable and assign the max date value. When joining put that value where the date is null as shown below.

```
Create table Table1 (Id int, [Item Name] varchar(20))
Insert into Table1 Values (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')

Create table Table2 (Id2 int, dtDate Date)
Insert into Table2 Values 
        (1, '01/01/2020'), (1, '01/11/2020'), (1, '01/21/2020'), (2, '01/01/2020')

declare @maxDtDate date
Select @maxDtDate = max(dtDate) from Table2

SELECT 
       A.[Item Name], 
       MAX(Isnull(B.[dtDate], @maxDtDate)) AS [Latest Date]
FROM [Table1] AS A LEFT JOIN [Table2] AS B ON A.[ID] = B.[ID2]
Group By A.[Item Name]
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59668e91a08e40c3bf650d0f8bf7b9e7)